# Error in Partial Upgrade

Tags: 20.04, sound, updates, 22.04, partial-upgrade

i have ubuntu 20 04 and want to upgrade to 22-04
i downloaded iso...but it don't worked...
i then decide to go through software updater
so i opened it
but it shows partial upgrade...which is dangerous..
so i decide to solve this
chat with ChatGPT and ChatGPT told that use terminal and something called sudo apt update, then upgrade, then dist-upgrade
so i do that and then restart...
now i am on a new ubuntu of 2204 but partially
all parts are something like with no desiningand no setting app and other app are also missing
then i again entered those commands and then restarted again
then much likely machine is improved but still not best...it is even partial
then i again do above process and again restart...
boom everything fine....except there is no voice and many of additional drivers are missing such as no camera, desktop icons missing(dont know whether they are missing or it is new feature?)
so i restarting again
no changment
then redirecting again to software updated
some partial upgrades again
but still problem is same

how can I solve this? I have desktop version

my machines response after some commands
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for kartik:
Hit:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

also tell me ...Q. are partial upgrades not safe and how to interact with them?

Comment: first off, make sure you're connected to the internet and try a `apt update ; apt install -f` and give us the output you receive, if at all possible (edit the question, do not add an answer) ... (also, don't use ChatGPT ... it doesn't know better)

Comment: If you have multiple unrelated problems after a failed upgrade, the likely best path is to reinstall the operating system cleanly. If you are not already adept at solving problems, this is the only practical solution when you have a lot of different problems.

Comment: You've not told us if you were using a Server system (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server) or Desktop System (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop), as to me that makes a difference (Desktop systems are easier to fix via non-destructive re-install for example; servers you clean install then restore data).

Comment: Based on your comments on the answer, you’re having trouble installing from usb. Look at these instructions https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview - your easiest option is probably to find a working windows machine you can access and download the iso again from the official source, then create the bootable usb from the iso with Rufus.

Comment: can i update system using bootable usb's method?..........means all my settings and data is still there or i have to format hdd again

Comment: Assume you’ll lose your data. Back it all up, install Ubuntu then copy your data across.

Comment: Your question mentions 20.04 (*focal*) and 22.04 (*jammy*), but your paste has a mixture of releases including *jammy* (22.04) and *kinetic* (22.10) thus conflicts with your actual story.  I'd suggest checking your facts & correcting your details as paste doesn't match what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were given terrible advice by ChatGPT. Following that advice has apparently damaged your system quite badly.

A "partial upgrade" is caused by a version conflict between packages. Usually, this is caused by packages that you installed from non-Ubuntu sources. In other words, it's self-inflicted.

The normal way you fix it is to delete the non-Ubuntu source and to uninstall every package from that source. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible.

Unfortunately, it's doubtful that you have the skill to do that safely. If you did have those skills, you would not have consulted ChatGPT for advice.

Therefore, the simplest and fastest way to fix the problem at your skill level is to back up your data and then to install Ubuntu 22.04 from the beginning.

Comment: yaa! i am not an expert in linux.....i am only 4-5 months old user of ubuntu

Comment: i tried using iso..as i mentioned earlier but i downloads iso in my mobile using utorrent but when i transfer this iso to my pc then this iso is corrupted....dont know why? some files are misssing in it...and it dont work...(i dont know what is scratch, i think its installing from starting?)